# Info Tip on Control Panel Item Windows 7

Tags: .net, windows-7, controlpanel

Based on this site - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh127450(v=vs.85).aspx, I was able to successfully add my application to the control panel. My problem is with hovering the mouse into the application icon in control panel. My application doesn't have a string table so directly set the string for InfoTip, ValueData:"description" and LocalizedString ValueData:"app name". I should expect that when I hover the mouse over the icon should display "description" but instead it displays "app name" which is the LocalizedString ValueData. I set the value type of both to reg_expand_sz. Is there something wrong with what I did? Please help.

Comment: You don't have any way of localizing the string.  So punt the problem and only provide the InfoTip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since LocalizedString is optional, and you put something in there that you don't want in your InfoTip, leave it out completely and you should see the result you're looking for. The documentation is pretty vague about what LocalizedString is used for. You're setting System.ApplicationName, right? That will make sure the name appears on Control Panel ok.